# BuddyPress | Check if user is in current group

Tags: users, user-roles, buddypress, members

I'm developing a plugin for a website, which uses the Group Extension API to create a new "subpage" in the group's page, just like Home, Members...

Here's the code:

```
class BP_Suggest extends BP_Group_Extension {

...

function display() {
    global $bp; 
    $group_id = $bp->groups->current_group->id;
    ?>
        <h2>
            Suggest Ideas to the group.
        </h2>
        <?php $this->print_all_suggestions($group_id); ?>


    <?php
}

...
```

I want to print, before the `$this->print_all_suggestions($group_id);` function, a form for posting a suggestion - but to print this form **only** is the user is logged in and is a member of the current group (which I have the ID of, like you've seen in line 2 of the function `display()`)
:

```
if(is_user_a_member_of_this_group()):
?>
    <div>
    ....
    </div>
<?php
else:
    echo "You don't have permissions to post here";
endif;
```

What should the function `is_user_a_member_of_this_group()` contain? (I'll probably change the name, don't worry ;) )

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function is_user_a_member_of_this_group($user_id, $group_id)
    //return: bool
    return groups_is_user_member( $user_id, $group_id );
}
```

Comment: Aside from the question being off topic, you might want to explain _why_ something is a solution (not needed for this question).

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry if it was off-topic, next time I'll go to Stackoverflow. I understand why it's the solution.. because that's how BuddyPress decided to call their function :)

Comment: There is also https://buddypress.org/support/